# Installed xcode 4.0.2 from CD unable to view ios application menu in new project option

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I newly installed xcode 4.0.2 from the application cd running on snow leopard 10.6.8 but im unable to view the ios SDk.I download a sample iphone app it says "BASE SDK Missing" i also checked in Build Setting for BASE SDK only MAC OS SDK option was there no IOS SDK ..I also reinstalled xcode for several times that didnt help .Is there any option to download only the SDK and use it with xcode ..idk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an iOS Developer Account, you can download Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard [here](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php). That'd be your best bet; it will have the SDKs for both iOS and Mac.

Comment: That's not correct. The Xcode 4.2 available from the App Store only supports lion, but from Apple as linked you can download a version for Snow Leopard, when logged in with a developer account—even a free one.

Comment: [link]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html well this doc say we can install xcode 4.2 for SN whereas the App store say  Xcode 4.2 is only for Lion ... :(
im so pissed off for last 3 days ....

Comment: Corrected—requires a paid iOS developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I mailed this issue to apple developer support - Xcode 4.2 for snow leopard is available for paid Apple Developer Program only.